# Particle Photon micro-controller UDP WiFi connection to custom Android App

Tags: android, udp, wifi, microcontroller

I have a WiFi enabled Particle Photon microcontroller that is wish to send UDP packets from to an android app, but i cant figure out the connections stuff.

The Particle Photon uses the same code language and libraries as arduino. The Code for that side is below:

```
// UDP Port used for two way communication
unsigned int localPort = 9876;

// An UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
  UDP Udp;

  void setup() 
  {
    // start the UDP
    Udp.begin(localPort);

    // Print your device IP Address via serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //this has been returining 192.168.xxx.xxx
  }





void loop() 
{
// Check if data has been received
if (Udp.parsePacket() > 0) {

// Read first char of data received
char c = Udp.read();

// Ignore other chars
Udp.flush();

// Store sender ip and port
IPAddress ipAddress = Udp.remoteIP();
int port = Udp.remotePort();

// Echo back data to sender
Udp.beginPacket(ipAddress, port);
Udp.write(c);
Serial.println(c);
Serial.println(port)
Udp.endPacket();
}

}
```

And the android App code is here:

```
package com.ucc.simon.wifi_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WifiManager w;
TextView status;
InetAddress server_ip;
int server_port = 9876;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IP_1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IP_2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IP_3);
    EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IP_4);

    String IP_text = editText1.getText().toString() + "." +
                     editText2.getText().toString() + "." +
                     editText3.getText().toString() + "." +
                     editText4.getText().toString();


    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    w = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (!w.isWifiEnabled()) {
        status.setText("switching ON wifi ");
        w.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } else {
        status.setText("Its already ON ");

    }



}

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    int x;
    WifiInfo info = w.getConnectionInfo();
    status.setText(" ");
    status.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

    x = info.getIpAddress();
    String str1 = info.getMacAddress();

    status.append("\n\nmac address===" + str1 + "  ,ip===" + x);

    try {
        server_ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.237"); // ip of my phone
        //server_ip = InetAddress.getByName(IP_text);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        status.append("Error at fetching inetAddress");
    }



    String str2 = "TEST MESSAGE !!!";
    byte b1[];
    b1 = new byte[100];
    b1 = str2.getBytes();
    //DatagramPacket p1 = new DatagramPacket(b1, b1.length, server_ip, server_port);



    try {
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port, server_ip);

        DatagramPacket p0 = new DatagramPacket(b1, b1.length, server_ip, server_port);



        DatagramPacket p1 = new DatagramPacket(b1,b1.length);
        s.receive(p1);

        b1=p1.getData();
        String str = new String( b1);

        server_port = p1.getPort();
        server_ip=p1.getAddress();


        String str_msg = "RECIEVED FROM CLIENT IP =" + server_ip + " port=" + server_port + " data=" + str;
        status.setText(str_msg);

    } catch (SocketException e)
    {
        status.append("Error creating socket");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        status.append("Error recieving packet");
    }
}
```

}

The phone running the app is connected via wifi to my network, not the microcontroller - i didn't see any way of changing this, as the micro doesn't broadcast its wifi network.

Also the required permissions have been declared in the manifest.